# How could I install custom Grub2 menus that have been received from an external source?

Tags: grub2

I got some custom Grub menus from [here](http://grub.gibibit.com/) and I would like to know how to install them to Grub. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That looks like grub legacy, not grub2 which Ubuntu has used since 2009. If your system is UEFI, use rEFInd. If BIOS look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays or: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to download [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer)

Under general settings change it to `show menu` if it isn't already set that way then go to the Appearance settings tab. You will select a theme there and then click save and you are good to go.

As for installing those you downloaded you can install them by extracting them into a folder then going to that folder in a command prompt and typing

```
sudo ./install /boot/grub/themes
```

Once you do this .. they will show up in Grub Customizer to select .. one note tho .. I tried 2 of them and they don't work. I get an error and have to press a key to continue. If you want one that works you need to use

```
sudo apt-get install grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate
```

This one does work and maybe you can use it to make one of your own that does work or use it to maybe figure out why the other ones don't work